# Getting scroll position for javascript show hide Nav

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, show-hide, nav

I am using some *stock* javascript to hide a Nav when scrolling down and show again when scrolling up.

It works perfectly except for Safari mobile.

When the page is scrolled down then dragged up past the top, or the Nav is at page top and you drag the screen down, the elastic/overscroll on Safari causes the scroll position to be greater than 0 and hides the Nav.

My *hope* is to make a work-around by only invoking the javascript after scrolling down e.g 100px.

My problem in modifying this code is at the least, a lack of javascript language basics.

Here is the code that works perfectly on desktop browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
/* ID Phlox:site-header Elementor Custom:iz-nav  */
function getBodyScrollTop () { const el = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement return el.scrollTop }
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos ) {
    document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "-60px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 
</script>
```

Here are 2 examples of what I tried to add/change to that script so the Nav was visible (*style.top = "0"*) when the scroll was between 0 and 100 px.

Basically 'get' the scroll pos variable and use the && (AND) || (OR) operators for the logic conditions.

1)

```
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos && currentScrollPos > 100 ) {
document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0";
```

2)

```
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos || window.pageYOffset < 100 ) {
document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0"
```

Am I even close to how it should be written?